# Enquiry on an inequality involving the sum of the reciprocals of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_k$ denote the $k-th$ prime. Do there exist some constant $A>0$ such that for every sufficiently large $k$,

$$\sum_{p\leq p_k} \frac{1}{p} >  B + \log\log p_k + \frac{A}{\log p_k}$$

where $B$ is the Mertens constant?

It is known that

$$\sum_{p\leq p_k} \frac{1}{p} =  B + \log\log p_k + O\left(\frac{1}{\log p_k} \right)$$

but nothing seems to be known about the sign of the implicit constant in the Landau $O$-symbol.

Comment: No. Mertens original paper has the opposite inequality with some terms plus 4/log(n+1), which means you can compute n_0 for which A=5 works for n bigger than n_0 for the opposite inequality. Also, there is oscillation (see Diamond and Pintz) which means your inequality with any positive A fails infinitely often.  Gerhard "Goes This Way And That" Paseman, 2017.05.13.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: why not posting this as an answer?

Comment: Because I don't know if the question has a typo.  If the question is meant as asked, I may post an answer.  Gerhard "Isn't Sure Of The Question" Paseman, 2017.05.13.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504289 on the proof of Mertens by Mark Villarino.  He shows that in fact the opposite inequality (less than) holds with A=4, and also shows the error term from the original proof (with an additional 2/(n ln n) term) and calculation of B.  I believe there are some oscillation results by Diamond and Pintz which would show that the posted inequality (greater than) never holds for all n sufficiently large for any positive A .

Gerhard "Now On The Right Side" Paseman, 2017.05.14.